# How to change variables in a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, change-of-variable

I'm reading that in the confluent hypergeometric equation 
$$z\frac{d^2w}{dz^2}+(c-z)\frac{dw}{dz}-aw = 0$$ 
the change of variables $x = bz$ transforms this into

$$\frac{x}{b}\frac{b-x}{b}(b^2w'')+\left(c-(a+b+1)\frac{x}{b}\right)(bw')-abw = 0$$

This makes little sense to me--I see of course how $z$ transforms into $\frac{x}{b}$ but where did $\frac{b-x}{b}$ come from?  I can identify this as $(1-z)$ but that was not a coefficient of the second-order term before the transformation.

And I would think that, if $w(z)=v(zb)$, then

$$\frac{d}{dz}w(z) = \frac{d}{dz}v(zb) = v'(zb)\cdot b$$

and

$$\frac{d^2}{dz^2}w(z) = \frac{d}{dz}v'(zb)\cdot b = b^2v''(zb)$$

and from here we could evaluate the DE in terms of $v$.  But it seems to me something very different is going on.  Perhaps $b$ here is not a constant as I've been assuming, but treating it as a variable would not result in the transformation described above, so I'm pretty thoroughly confused.

Comment: Are you sure this transformed differential equation is correct ?

Comment: The transformed ODE is not correct.

Comment: The solution is given by $$w(z)=c_1 U(a,c,z)+c_2 L_{-a}^{c-1}(z)$$

Comment: @Addem you are saying b is variable here, but then your transformed differential equation must involve derivatives of b also.

Comment: @ManojKumar I'm not sure if it's correct, but before the transformation other sources show this is the confluent hypergeometric equation.  The result of the transformation matches the general hypergeometric equation.  So that is some kind of indication that the author is at least somehow correct, although I have no idea how the given transformation takes you from one equation to the other.

Comment: And I'm not sure if $b$ is a variable or not, as I noted in the question.  If it is a variable, as I noted, that doesn't seem to resolve the issue because it still doesn't result in the second DE.